# SQL Error (1100): Table 'authors' was not locked with LOCK TABLES query

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x, database

would any one help me in these error
when import data in client machine ,,, i found these error

[image: SQL Error (1100)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following might be the case for you.

Let's say you locked one table but want to select from another table, you must either lock that table too or unlock all tables.

```
mysql> LOCK TABLES myTable READ;
mysql> SELECT COUNTY FROM myTable WHERE CITY = 'DUBLIN';
+----------+
| COUNTY   |
+----------+
|  Alameada|
+----------+
mysql> SELECT COUNTRY FROM myTableT2;
ERROR 1100 (HY000): Table 'myTableT2' was not locked with LOCK TABLES
```

read this document on how lock works https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html